# What did I do wrong when buying my domain through Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, domain-registrar

Several times in the past I've bought a domain through Google Apps, and every year Google automatically renews the domain for $10.

Somehow when I did this today, I ended up additionally being signed up for an annual Google Apps for Business plan at $12/license/yr.  I don't need this; I'm only one user.

I'd like to cancel this $12/yr Google Apps plan without cancelling the automatical $10/yr domain renewal.  However, there is no "cancel" or "downgrade" link, apparently (according to the help docs) because I have an annual pre-paid account.  If I choose not to auto-renew my annual account, it also declines auto-renewal of my domain.

How can I make this domain just like my others -- auto-renewed at $10/yr, with a free Google Apps account in front of it?

Comment: AFAIK you'd pick the [free option](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html) (left column) before you begin? I'm not sure where $12/yr comes from, I thought Google Apps for Business starts at $50/user/yr?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I was signed up for the Free edition, but misunderstood the UI.  Three things happened that caused me to misunderstand:

1. Google Apps are transitioning to a new billing system, so my new domain's Google Apps UI looked different from my old domains' UIs.  It has a "Billing & Subscriptions" tab.  I thought this meant I must have done something different.
2. Enom raised their registration rate from $10/yr to $12/yr, and the new Billing & Registration tab lists that fee as "$12/license/year" (IMO it should be listed as $12/domain/year)
3. Google Apps has a typo under the Domain Names tab, which separately lists registration of my domain at $10/yr.  They will update this to $12/yr for Enom.